# Verilog - Assigning a value to high

Tags: verilog

I'm in the process of building a 4 bit ALU in Verilog. We already built one using the gate placement, click and drag part of Quartus, and now we're doing Verilog. In the first assignment, I had some values set as VCC and some as GND. Is there a way i can do that in Verilog?

[image: This is for the first bit B value]

This is for the first bit B value. How can I replicate that in Verilog, setting I2 and I3 to VCC?

Here's what I have so far:

[image: MUX]

And here is my 4x1 MUX code:

[image: 4x1]

Comment: Think about what logical values do VCC and GND represent.

Comment: It seems to me that you've already done proper assignment in MUX_4x1 declaration.

Comment: I assumed the red colored ones means there is some problem, am I wrong about that?

Comment: you should provide code for the `MUX_4x1` module as well, or at least port declarations for it.

Comment: Good idea, I added the 4x1 code.

Answer (score 1):

You normally use ones and zeros in a Verilog simulation to indicate high or low value.

```
assign byte_set_to_all_ones  = 8'b11111111; // or 8'hFF
assign byte_set_to_all_zeros = 8'b00000000; // or 8'h00
```

As you mention VCC and GND:
Verilog has a number of 'strength' signals. This allows a stronger signal to 'win' from a weaker signal. The greatest strength is if you use supplyX. There is supply1 (for high) and supply0 (for low).  For more information look [here](http://verilog.renerta.com/source/vrg00047.htm).
You are unlikely to need those until you have had about half a dozen years of Verilog coding behind you.

---

Let me elaborate on my preferred usage of 1'b1 versus 1:
Your red 1 will work as well, in this case, as they will be converted from 32 bit-wide to one bit-wide (the size of the port). The use of 1'b1 is better, just like it is better to call a C function with the right size argument. 
Also the person reading the code will know with 1'b1, that it is a one bit input, but with '1' she/he may think that its is a 32-bit wide port.

Using the right size constant is a very good habit in Verilog. Someday you want to concatenate bits using { ...} and there use 1 or 1'b1 makes a huge difference!

Comment: So am I okay with my MUX_4x1 declaration there? Could I replace the red 1's with supply1?

Comment: It is good practice to use the correct vector length. Thus a single bit is 1'b1 or 1'b0, two bits is 2'b00, 2'b11 etc.  No, do **not** use supply1 or supply0 until you have done about a hundred designs and know when to use them.

Comment: Awesome, so instead of the red ones there, I should put 1'b1, 1'b1 and that'll work?